# Explicitly positive integer in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: gql, google-cloud-datastore

I was studing the [Google Cloud Datastore GQL grammar and behavior](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/gql?hl=en#tips_about_gql_behavior) when I found the "*explicity positive integer*" concept. Someone could tell me an example of its usability? I think that with an example I could understand better the importance and use of this type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *explicitly positive integer* concept is something taken from SQL. [Here is a link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements003.htm#i139900) from the Oracle SQL database docs since it includes a nice infographic, but you can also check out the [SQL paper (1992)](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and search for "<signed integer literal>".

The main reason this exists is just for completeness, in your normal use of GQL it is ok to just leave the operator off to specify a positive number.

My best guess as to when you would actually use this is if you were building a GQL string and found it useful to add a modifier regardless of if a number is positive or negative.